# Trying to get pagination to adjust when filtering table rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get pagination to adjust the number of pages when I filter by customer number. When I search for customer number CYR is should adjust the pagination to 1 page but it seems to be calculating the pages on page load.

Here is the filterCust function:

```
function filterCust() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("custfilter");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("invtable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the Pagination script

```
/* PAGINATION SCRIPT */
// Returns an array of maxLength (or less) page numbers
// where a 0 in the returned array denotes a gap in the series.
// Parameters:
//   totalPages:     total number of pages
//   page:           current page
//   maxLength:      maximum size of returned array
function getPageList(totalPages, page, maxLength) {
  if (maxLength < 5) throw "maxLength must be at least 5";

  function range(start, end) {
    return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), (_, i) => i + start);
  }

  var sideWidth = maxLength < 9 ? 1 : 2;
  var leftWidth = (maxLength - sideWidth * 2 - 3) >> 1;
  var rightWidth = (maxLength - sideWidth * 2 - 2) >> 1;
  if (totalPages <= maxLength) {
    // no breaks in list
    return range(1, totalPages);
  }
  if (page <= maxLength - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth) {
    // no break on left of page
    return range(1, maxLength - sideWidth - 1)
      .concat([0])
      .concat(range(totalPages - sideWidth + 1, totalPages));
  }
  if (page >= totalPages - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth) {
    // no break on right of page
    return range(1, sideWidth)
      .concat([0])
      .concat(
        range(totalPages - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth - leftWidth, totalPages)
      );
  }
  // Breaks on both sides
  return range(1, sideWidth)
    .concat([0])
    .concat(range(page - leftWidth, page + rightWidth))
    .concat([0])
    .concat(range(totalPages - sideWidth + 1, totalPages));
}

$(function() {
  // Number of items and limits the number of items per page
  var numberOfItems = $("#invtable .content").length;
  var limitPerPage = 8;
  // Total pages rounded upwards
  var totalPages = Math.ceil(numberOfItems / limitPerPage);
  // Number of buttons at the top, not counting prev/next,
  // but including the dotted buttons.
  // Must be at least 5:
  var paginationSize = 7;
  var currentPage;

  function showPage(whichPage) {
    if (whichPage < 1 || whichPage > totalPages) return false;
    currentPage = whichPage;
    $("#invtable .content")
      .hide()
      .slice((currentPage - 1) * limitPerPage, currentPage * limitPerPage)
      .show();
    // Replace the navigation items (not prev/next):
    $(".pagination li").slice(1, -1).remove();
    getPageList(totalPages, currentPage, paginationSize).forEach(item => {
      $("<li>")
        .addClass(
          "page-item " +
          (item ? "current-page " : "") +
          (item === currentPage ? "active " : "")
        )
        .append(
          $("<a>")
          .addClass("page-link")
          .attr({
            href: "javascript:void(0)"
          })
          .text(item || "...")
        )
        .insertBefore("#next-page");
    });
    return true;
  }

  // Include the prev/next buttons:
  $(".pagination").append(
    $("<li>").addClass("page-item").attr({
      id: "previous-page"
    }).append(
      $("<a>")
      .addClass("page-link")
      .attr({
        href: "javascript:void(0)"
      })
      .text("Prev")
    ),
    $("<li>").addClass("page-item").attr({
      id: "next-page"
    }).append(
      $("<a>")
      .addClass("page-link")
      .attr({
        href: "javascript:void(0)"
      })
      .text("Next")
    )
  );
  // Show the page links
  $("#invtable").show();
  showPage(1);

  // Use event delegation, as these items are recreated later
  $(
    document
  ).on("click", ".pagination li.current-page:not(.active)", function() {
    return showPage(+$(this).text());
  });
  $("#next-page").on("click", function() {
    return showPage(currentPage + 1);
  });

  $("#previous-page").on("click", function() {
    return showPage(currentPage - 1);
  });
  $(".pagination").on("click", function() {
    $("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

You can see what I'm talking about here https://jsfiddle.net/htgs2ro4/ the formatting is a little off kind of new to jsfiddle.

Thanks in advance

Ralph

Comment: Your example fiddle doesn't filter at all - both customers remain in the list. Seems like maybe more than one problem.

Comment: If you type CYR you should see 3, it's working for me??

Comment: click on page 2, or 3, etc. the other one shows up.If you keep going, I was able to "filter" and get them all back as if there were no filter at all.

Comment: you should probably correct the JavaScript run-time exception associated with Popper too!

Comment: yes, that is why I need to adjust the number of pages when I filter a customer.  If it only showed one page after filtering the CYR customer it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you Randy, I have an idea now of how I can fix it!